# Help solve a Limit Question?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

See this [image].

What he's meant that "in particular"? where the $|g(x)|<|M|+1$ formula from? How deduced? What is the meaning of it?

Comment: It would be nice if you would write the exercise down instead of giving a link.

Comment: Is $M$ considerd to be positive-prior to the text we see in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
M-1<g(x)<M+1
$$
Now use the fact that $-|M|\le M\le |M|$, so
$$
-|M|-1\le M-1<g(x)<M+1\le |M|+1
$$
and the external terms tell you that
$$
|g(x)|<|M|+1
$$

The whole point is to prove that $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

One form of the triangle inequality is $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$.  Thus

$$|g(x)-M|\lt1\implies|g(x)|-|M|\le|g(x)-M|\lt1\implies|g(x)|\lt|M|+1$$